# Maven Surefire only "default-test" run custom executions ignored

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using maven 3.5.4, maven-surefire-plugin 2.19 (I tried maven-surefire-plugin 2.22 also - same result).
Here's the build section of my POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>20</threadCount>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludedGroups>switch-enabled</excludedGroups>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>other-tests</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>switch-enabled</groups>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have two sets of unit tests that need to run separately (due to a static boolean variable, thus I set up a TestNG group and have all the tests that need the switch to be on in that group).

Surefire only runs the "default-test" execution and ignore the other execution. I tried the following as well but it also didn't work - no tests were run instead:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>20</threadCount>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>true-tests</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>switch-enabled</groups>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>false-tests</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludedGroups>switch-enabled</excludedGroups>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `default-test` execution? Given that you're skipping it anyway.

Comment: @dryleaf yes, then all tests are run in a single execution, as default-test :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with surefire plugin. I would suggest you to move your tests run configuration to the testng .xml file, that would run each set separately and would also let you config parallel run for each:

```
    <suite name="Test-Suite">
    <test name="Test first set" parallel="20" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="domain.tests.com.TestA"/>
            <class name="domain.tests.com.TestB"/>
   // Classes of first set here..
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test second set" parallel="20" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="domain.tests.com.TestC"/>
            <class name="domain.tests.com.TestD"/>
   // Classes of second set here..
        </classes>
    </test>
    </suite>
```

Comment: I was thinking about trying xml or using profile as my last resort, and yes, it works with using xml :) Thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the XML file approach as suggested by @AutomatedOwl. I had to create a new group named "integration" that I apply at the class level for the integration test classes, as there is no direct way to exclude classes in TestNG XML and I do not want the integration tests to be run at the surefire test phase. Here's my TestNG XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestAll">
    <test name="falseTest" parallel="classes" thread-count="20">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="switch-enabled" />
                <exclude name="integration" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.somecomp" />
        </packages>
    </test>
    <test name="trueTest" parallel="classes" thread-count="20">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="switch-enabled" />
                <exclude name="integration" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.somecomp" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And here's the build section of my POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```